# How can I create and use an image larger than the screen resolution?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cgcontext

I'm trying to render a bitmap to save to the user's photos album that has to be higher resolution than the 320x480 iPhone screen (but still within iOS memory limitations).
However, using this code to create contexts:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(finalImgWidth, finalImgHeight));
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

or the CG analog:

```
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, finalImgWidth, finalImgHeight, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
```

returns a nil context if width or height is greater than 320x480.

Is there any other way to create a high-res image?

Note: I already know how to draw into contexts normally and take screenshots.  I need a solution that scales to typical photo resolution.

Comment: CHeckout this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119889/how-to-display-an-image-that-is-bigger-than-the-phone-screen-dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `[UIImage initWithCGImage:scale:orientation:]` ?

First, initialized an `UIImage` object with the image, to get the image's geometry.
Then calculate the scale factor.

Comment: I'm trying to draw the contents of a scrollview into one image, so I'm not sure how I'd start off with a CGImage.  To clarify, I have multiple UIImageViews that when combined are larger than the screen real estate.  I'm trying to render those into one final UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think it will help you. In the following Apple Sample codes, they show how to display a large image in the screen.

[Scrolling Apple Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm quite familiar with how to layout views in a scrollview.  This question is about how to turn a layout into a jpg/png file for viewing in the Photos app.